# Euler Lagrange Equation on special brachistochrone

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

I have to use the Euler Lagrange Equation on a special form of the brachistochrone, which includes gravity. So the formular would be:

$$
T[y]=\int_{a}^{b}\tfrac{\sqrt{1+y'((x))^2}}{\sqrt{(y(x)g(x)}}
$$

I then have the ELE:

$$
0=\tfrac{df}{dy}-\tfrac{d}{dx}(\tfrac{df}{dy'})
$$

and got

$$
\tfrac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{\sqrt{(y^3g}}=\tfrac{d}{dx}(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cdot \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \cdot y' \cdot \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}})
 $$

which all in all I brought down (using product rule for the derivative) to

$$-g \cdot (1+y'^2)=-g'yy' \cdot (1+y'^2)+2y''yg $$

For easier writing I stopped using the arguiment (x) in the end, I hope it is okay. How do I continue from here? I have seen approaches with the normal ELE, which use finding the right term for a derivative and then integrating, but I can't find it here. Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance. I hope, I did not make any mistakes in calculating or writing the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Lagrangian, i.e. the function $f$, is independent of $x$, you cannot use the Euler-Lagrange equations. Instead, use the Beltrami's identity, which is  a degenerate case of the Euler-Lagrange equations.

So if you had to optimise $I$,
$$I=\int_a^b f(y,y') dx$$
Then use the Beltrami's identity,
$$f-y'\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y'} =c$$
Where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. This should simplify your equation tremendously.

This means in your case, the Lagrangian would be
$$f(y,y')=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}{\sqrt{yg}}$$
Applying the Beltrami's identity,
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}{\sqrt{yg}}-y'\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y'}\left[\dfrac{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}{\sqrt{yg}}\right]=c$$
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}{\sqrt{yg}}-\dfrac{(y')^2}{\sqrt{yg}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}=c$$
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{yg}\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}=c$$
$$\sqrt{1+(y')^2}=\dfrac{1}{c\sqrt{yg}}$$
$$y' = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{c^2gy}-1}$$